# React native screen navigation is slow

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I using react navigation with functional components and i am facing a issue that screen when move from one screen to another. it is taking 1-2 seconds. Users are able to observe that something is loading. I am using

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.1",

<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='HomeScreen' component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
</Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

HomeScreen

```
<Tab.Navigator>
```

Some tabs
</Tab.Navigator>

So i am not able to know what is problem. i found some solution with Interaction manager.  So please provide me a answer how can i do this in the functional components and increase navigation speed.

Comment: Please add more information, like what is the code that you are using, perhaps a video of the issue? Is the app always slow to everyone or just some devices? The dependencies alone gives almost nothing to being with.

Comment: @sfratini code updated please check.

Comment: This is unlikely to be solvable with this minimal amount of information and no way to reproduce it.

Comment: @sfratini you can check this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7756 it will provide you more information that there is something is react-navigation. As in my code there are lot of things so i don't it will resolve like this. you can check above github definitely it will help you to understand and may we fix it soon.

Comment: I am not understanding what you expect. You have an already existing bug reported from that library. Unless they fix that issue, you are not going to make it better. The suggest having less tabs, have you tried that? Also, the code you added gives not much to review. You have a home screen, that is all I can see there. How many tabs you have? Are they all nested? How are you calling them from one to the other? I am voting to close this one, has no information to follow.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the amount of time it takes to navigate from one screen to another using 'animationDuration' option.

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, animation: "slide_from_right", animationDuration: 1 }}>
```